# How can I change my merchant account within QuickBooks?

Tags: quickbooks

I lost access to the original e-mail used for my Intuit QuickBooks Payments account and had to start fresh with a new account. Unfortunately, the old account is still baked in to my company file and I cannot find any way of unlinking it to use the new one.

How can I do this in QuickBooks Desktop 2014?

Answer (score 0):

1. With your company file open, press <kbd>F2</kbd>. This will open the Product Information window.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and click 'Yes' when prompted to clear your AuthID. [image: Clear Upload Times or AuthID prompt]
3. Restart QuickBooks
4. Use <kbd>Customers > Link Payment Service to Company File</kbd>
5. Log in with your new merchant account credentials